# JQuery - how i can get variable of "file.JS"

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I pass a list of a arquivo.js for html

**Example:**

*file1.js:*

*i have this variable in file1.js:*

```
vList = []
```

*index.html:*

```
//need Get vList here
```

How can i get vList?

How can i make this ?

PS: vList is one matrix of the DOM Object

**Need get one variable in file1.js**

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js" ></script>
```

Comment: +1 for you understanding, what did he want.

Comment: need to get a variable that is in one file.js "file1.js"